# Does the "Intermediate Language Runtime" (not sure what to call it) enforce sealed classes having no derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# you can make a class sealed. Then you cannot use that class as a base class for another. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed

Does the "Intermediate Language Runtime" (not sure what to call it) enforce this?

If not, could someone generate Intermediate Language code by hand that derives from a sealed class?

Comment: Have you tried creating the IL code to inherit from a `sealed` class?

Comment: @Dai Thanks! Does that mean the JIT either enforces or does not enforce this? If so, does it enforce sealing of classes, or not?

Comment: @julealgon No, I haven't

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeattributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C# you can make a class `sealed`. Then you cannot use that class as a base class for another.

Correct.

However, be judicious with the `sealed` keyword. Don't *preemptively* add `sealed` to all of your types without good-cause.

> Does the "Intermediate Language Runtime" (not sure what to call it) enforce this?

It's enforced at multiple points, by separate components. I can think of 2 scenarios right now:

- If you define a `class` in a C# project that extends a `sealed` class (either in the same project or in a referenced assembly) then you'll get a compile-time error:

  > [CS0509 "A sealed class cannot act as a base class."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0509).
- If you defined a `class` in a C# project that extends a *non*-sealed `class` in a referenced assembly, and then build/compile your project, and then replace the referenced assembly with an updated assembly where the class is now `sealed` then you'll get a runtime error when the CLR tries to *load* your derived class (as types are generally *loaded* on-demand: at the point where they're first-used, this is also when `static` constructors and type-initializers are invoked):

  > Unhandled exception. `System.TypeLoadException`: Could not load type 'ConsoleApp1.Derived' from assembly 'ConsoleApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' **because the parent type is sealed**.
  > at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)

  - The `TypeLoadException` for this is thrown at the point where a type is loaded, which is nondeterministic. This is why it's a bad idea to replace assemblies/binaries *in production* without rebuilding the consuming projects from-source to catch these issues beforehand.

---

### Example project:

#### ConsoleProject1.csproj + Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Derived : ClassLibrary1.SomeClass
    {
        public Derived()
        {
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            ClassLibrary1.SomeClass foo = new Derived();

            Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!" );

            Console.WriteLine( foo.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

#### LibraryProject.csproj + Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public /*sealed*/ class SomeClass // <-- Rebuild this twice, uncommenting the `sealed` keyword for the second build.
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That was fast, thorough, informative and easy-to-read!!!

Comment: Not directly related to the question at hand but at the comment regarding sealing classes by default. There are vast benefits for doing so, benefits not only related to performance but code simplicity and robustness as well. Implementing `IDisposable` is much simpler, there is a lot less risk for inadvertent breaking changes from inheritors, etc. I'd advise anyone looking at the comment here to check other sources for further information on why it might be a good idea to seal by default. I myself have been doing that for several years now to great effect.

Comment: @julealgon I agree, implementing `IDisposable` with `sealed` is a good idea. I should have clarified my remarks as referring to _business domain_ types (which shouldn't normally need to implement `IDisposable` as they should all be POCOs).